# Laravel and Android get and post

Tags: android, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am kind of new with laravel and currently I am working on an android application where I have to call a laravel controller. 
I was trying to call a function (just returning a string, the name of the function is androidTest) from android but each time it ended up throwing an exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException:http://192.168.0.104/LaravelAjaxRes/public/getRequest
I checked the URL properly, its perfectly ok. I also disabled CSRF verification but still it did not work! 
Can anyone tell what I am missing and is there any tutorial or something that can help me? Thanks in advance.
Controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use DB;

class getRegistrationData extends Controller
{
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        $data = json_encode($request->all());

        $parse = json_decode($data);



        $teachers_name_array = $this->splitTeacherName($parse->teacher);

        $teacher_id = $this->getTeacherID($teachers_name_array);


        DB::table('lessons')->insert(
            ['title' => $parse->title, 'description' => $parse->description,'teacher_id' => $teacher_id]
        );
    }
    else{

    }

}

public function getTeachersData(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        $teachers = DB::table('teachers')->select('firstname', 'lastname')->get();
        return $teachers;
    }
    else{
        //$teachers = DB::table('teachers')->select('firstname', 'lastname')->get();

    }
}

public function androidTest()
{
    echo 'Some Text';
}





public function splitTeacherName($teacher_full_name)
{
    return explode(" ", $teacher_full_name);
}




public function getTeacherID($teachers_name_array)
{
    $matchNames = ['firstname' => $teachers_name_array[0], 'lastname' => $teachers_name_array[1]];
    $result = DB::table('teachers')->select('id')->where($matchNames)->get();

    foreach ($result as $t_id) 
    {
        $teacher_id = $t_id->id;
    }

    return $teacher_id;
}

public function getLessonData(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        $lessons = 
        DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT d1.* ,d2.* from teachers d1 INNER JOIN lessons d2 where d1.id = d2.teacher_id'));
        return $lessons;
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

route code:

```
`Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
 });
 Route::post('/register','getRegistrationData@index');

 Route::get('/getRequest','getRegistrationData@androidTest');

 Route::get('/getLessonRequest','getRegistrationData@getLessonData');`
```

Comment: Can you paste your routes and controller codes here ? Unless it's hard to go through the problem ?

Comment: Check fot .htaccess in public directory. It's allows to access without index.php ?

Comment: @MahfuzulAlam I edited and included all codes. Maybe you can help now !

Comment: @Chintan7027 Yes I checked. It does

Comment: @ctx I checked your code in my local environment and also tested with postman. Nothing is wrong with your code in server side. May be the problem is in your android side. Re-check if your request method is GET or not.